# Get Bootstrap tabs to work in Xages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, xpages

I want to put a tabbed interface in an Xpage on one of my apps. Using Bootstrap for the Ui.

This works great:

```
<xp:div styleClass="row">
            <xp:div styleClass="col-sm-12">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Inventory</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a data-target="#menu1" data-toggle="tab">Being Built</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a data-target="#menu2" data-toggle="tab">Deployed</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">Inventory</div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="menu1">Being Built</div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="menu2">Deployed</div>
                </div>
            </xp:div>
        </xp:div>

        <xp:div styleClass="row">
            <xp:div styleClass="col-sm-12">

                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="ul1">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a data-target="#xhome" data-toggle="tab">Inventory</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a data-target="#xmenu1" data-toggle="tab">Being Built</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a data-target="#xmenu2" data-toggle="tab">Deployed</a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
```

But typically I turn any straight HTML into xp tags so I can use things like disabled and the other Xpages controls and attributes. For example, depending on the status of the document, I want to hide and/or disable some tabs. I find that easier to do with Xpages.

But I have tried all kinds of controls, like inline lists, tabbed panels and nothing works like the html code here.

Is there some Xpage controls that will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I totally follow you.  I think you want something like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>
        <xp:link styleClass="navbar-brand" text="Home" value="/basic_Menu.xsp"
        id="link1" />
    </li> 
        <xp:panel tagName="li" rendered="#{controller.myObject.isValid}">
                <xp:link text="#{param.myUrlParam}" >
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return "/myPage.xsp?jobId=" + param.get("myUrlParam")}]]></xp:this.value>
                                </xp:link>
                            </xp:panel>
                        </ul>
```

This is a snippet from Bootstrap code I use in a navBar.  There is no `<xp:li>` tag right?  So you have to use `<li>` straight.  BUT if you use a panel and change the tagName to "li" then in effect it becomes "" and you can use all the properties of a panel like rendered.

So use bootstrap code like you posted and then add in this technique where needed.  There is also an `<xp:span>` which might also be helpful - though I use panels for most of this stuff.

Comment: Both of these methods work - verified over the weekend. For my purposes using a panel works best.

Answer (score 1):

David's approach is a good one.
In one of my apps I also use the Bootstrap tabs and made the hide when on li tag directly

```
<li role="presentation"
                        style="display:#{javascript:(account.isNewNote())? 'none':'block;'}">
                        <a href="#banking" aria-controls="banking" role="tab"
                            data-toggle="tab">
                            <xp:text>
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:language.getLanguageString("page.account.tab.banking")}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:text>
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

Comment: Frank's techinique would work as well.  I guess 1 key difference between the two is since he's basically doing "display:none" any code inside that will still be sent to the browser.  By using rendered in my example - XPages will work out the inside of the code but data won't be sent to the browser. I'm not suggesting either is better.  There's just a little different behavior.